# Is there a way to rebuild ns2 in fedoracore4 linux OS after replace multiple files in core of ns2?

Tags: linux, replace, ns2, rebuild, reinstall

How to rebuild `ns2` in **Fedora Core 4 Linux OS** after replacing multiple files in the core of `ns2`?
Do I have to uninstall and reinstall the `ns2`  completely or is there any other way?

Comment: You can have as many ns-allinone-2.xx as you want, installed at the same time : ns2 INFO https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing ......... ns2-patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?resourcekey=0-eBw6mJFKhSVGultqaD2rDA&usp=sharing ......... Not always possible to reuse a modified ns2. So simply build a new one in a new directory.

Comment: Rebuild ns2 after a modification : **1**. ns-2.26 .. 2.34 is like `make clean && ./configure && make` .......... **2**.  ns-2.35 : Please use the `./install` command in ns-allinone-2.35/, which will take care of all `make clean && ./configure && make`